# Permission denied error when getting the location on the Production site in google Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-chrome, geolocation, gps

Best regards, I wanted to see if there is a possibility that someone could help me solve the following problem:

It turns out that with a javascript code I get the location, and testing it from localhost works correctly in all browsers, but when I publish it on the server or production site, I get an error, that the permission has been denied, but this only happens in Google Chrome, already in Internet Explorer works for me in production. The code is the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var nav = null; 

    function requestPosition() {
        if (nav == null) {
            nav = window.navigator;
        }

        var geoloc = nav.geolocation;
        if (geoloc != null) {
            geoloc.getCurrentPosition(successCallback, errorCallback);
        }

    }

    function successCallback(position) {
        document.getElementById("latitude").innerHTML = 
            position.coords.latitude;
        document.getElementById("longitude").innerHTML = 
            position.coords.longitude;

    }

    function errorCallback(error) {
        var strMessage = "";

        // Check for known errors
        switch (error.code) {
            case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
                strMessage = "Access to your location is turned off. "  +
                    "Change your settings to turn it back on.";
                break;
            case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
                strMessage = "Data from location services is " + 
                    "currently unavailable.";
                break;
            case error.TIMEOUT:
                strMessage = "Location could not be determined " +
                    "within a specified timeout period.";
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = strMessage;
    }

</script>

        <label for="latitude">Latitude: </label> <div id="latitude"></div><br />
        <label for="longitude">Longitude: </label> <div id="longitude"> </div><br />
        <div id="status"> </div><br />
        <input type="button" onclick="requestPosition()" value="Get Latitude and Longitude"  />
```

When the web application is in the production site, the error goes through the validation line of the **CASE error.PERMISSION_DENIED**:

I do not know why it works for me on localhost, but when it's on the website, it gives that error. If someone has any ideas, I would appreciate it, I imagine that some part will have to enable some permission, but the logical thing should be from the client, and not from the server, since I want to obtain the client's location, from any part where you can find me.

When inspecting in the browser console it tells me the following error in the function: eoloc.getCurrentPosition (successCallback, errorCallback)

getCurrentPosition() and watchPosition() no longer work on insecure origins. To use this feature, you should consider switching your application to a secure origin, such as HTTPS. See goo.gl/rStTGz for more details."

Comment: Is protocol `https`?

Comment: no, it's not safe, http

Comment: Chrome has `https` requirement. https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/04/geolocation-on-secure-contexts-only

Comment: Edit the question specifying the error

Comment: If you want to use geolocation, you have to use https: (or a different, less accurate location service; like by IP address)